# ¿Cómo puedo crear un método remove_product y un método find_product en la clase Catalogue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase

El ejemplo está constituido por dos clases `Product` y `Catalogue`:

**Clase `Product`:**

```
class Product:
    und = {}

        def __init__(self, code, descripcion, precio):
            self.code = code
            self.descripcion = descripcion
            self.precio = precio
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "El codigo es  {} con la descripcion {} ".format(self.code, self.descripcion)
    
        def agregar_uni(self, code, descripcion, precio):
            self.und[code] = descripcion, precio
    
        def mostrar_todos(self):
            print("Las unidades  son: ")
            for i in self.und.keys():
                print("Code: " + str(i))
                print("Descripcion: " + str(self.und[i]))
    
        def __eq__(self, product):
            if self.code == product.code:
                Print("Hay un elemento duplicado")
            else:
                pass
    
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self._code)
```

He seguido las indicaciones de mi profesor... Seguro que vuestros códigos están bien, incluso mejor que éste. Pero tengo que seguir está senda.¿Alguna idea para crear un método que borre productos en la clase Catalogue?. Aprovecho también para saber realizar un método que también busque un producto en la clase Catalogue.

**Clase `Catalogue`:**

```
 class Catalogue():
    
            def __init__(self):
                self.catalogo = {}
        
            def add_product(self,producto):
                self.catalogo[producto.code] = producto
                t = Product(code="1", descripcion="Llaves Allen", precio="40€")
                t1 = Product(code="2", descripcion="Bombillas", precio="12€")
                t3 = Product(code="3", descripcion="Destornillador", precio="20€")
        
                Catalogue().add_product(t, t1,t3 )
            
        
        
        
        
        t = Product(code="1", descripcion="Llaves Allen", precio="40€")
        t = Catalogue()
        t = Product(code="1", descripcion="Llaves Allen", precio="40€")
        t1 = Product(code="2", descripcion="Bombillas", precio="12€")
        t3 = Product(code="3", descripcion="Destornillador", precio="20€")
        print("\n",t,"\n",t1,"\n", t3)
```

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, lo que pretendes es tomar un producto de la clase `product` y disponerlo en la clase `catalogue`. Si este es tú propósito, porque no **heredas** la clase `catalogue` de la clase `product` de la forma: `class Catalogue(Product):` de esta forma puedes **heredar no solo el objeto sino los atributos**

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta. Estoy empezando en python y en programación, y no sabía como.. Intentaré hacer lo que me comentas. Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que después de heredar la clase; sería crear un nuevo diccionario en catalogo donde voy añadiendo los productos de Product. Sería algo así?

Comment: Disculpa, no tengo puntos para responder al comentario, asique escribo otra respuesta a tu comentario,
Si, una vez que tienes el catalogo y has pasado un producto, solo tienes que hacer un diccionario o vector de productos y los vas guardando ahi, en el caso de lenguajes mas tipados como C# o Java, tendrias que hacer explicitamente un vector de productos como :
Product miVector[] = new Product(), pero en python con que crees un diccionario y vallas agrenado productos ya funciona, espero que te haya servido de ayuda! Saludos

Comment: 0


Disculpa Jony Cash por mi desconocimiento. Si tengo creado tres productos en la clase -Product-. ¿Escribiendo tu código sería posible entonces almacenar esos tres productos en la clase -Catalogue- en un nuevo diccionario?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel.

De acuerdo con lo que escribes, cambié un poco la lógica en tu código. Básicamente ahora puedes llegar un catálogo de productos, pasando como argumento productos. Un enfoque diferente sería almacenar directamente los objetos de tipo producto dentro del catálogo.

Como salida al ejecutar el código obtienes:

```
El producto "LLave inglesa" se ha agregado al catálogo

El producto "Llaves Allen" se ha agregado al catálogo

El producto "Destronillador" se ha agregado al catálogo

***Catálogo de productos***

Code: 1
  Descripcion: LLave inglesa
  Precio: 40€
---------------------------------
Code: 2
  Descripcion: Llaves Allen
  Precio: 40€
---------------------------------
Code: 3
  Descripcion: Destronillador
  Precio: 20€
---------------------------------
El producto "LLave inglesa" ya existe en el catalogo
```

El código sería el siguiente:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, code, descripcion, precio):
        self.code = code
        self.descripcion = descripcion
        self.precio = precio

    def __eq__(self, product):
        return self.code == product.code

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._code)

    def __str__(self):
        return "El codigo es  {} con la descripcion {} ".format(self.code, self.descripcion)


class Catalogue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.catalogue = {}

    def add_product(self, product):
        if self.check_product(product):
            print(f'El producto "{product.descripcion}" ya existe en el catalogo')

        else:
            self.catalogue[product.code] = {'Descripción': product.descripcion, 'Precio': product.precio}
            print(f'El producto "{product.descripcion}" se ha agregado al catálogo\n')

    def mostrar_todos(self):
        print("\n\n\n***Catálogo de productos***\n")
        for code, item in self.catalogue.items():
            print("Code: " + str(code))
            print("  Descripcion: " + item['Descripción'])
            print("  Precio: " + item['Precio'])
            print('---------------------------------')

    def check_product(self, product):
        return product.code in self.catalogue.keys()

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Creación de un catálogo
    catalogue = Catalogue()

    # Creación de tres productos
    product1 = Product(code="1", descripcion="LLave inglesa", precio="40€")
    product2 = Product(code="2", descripcion="Llaves Allen", precio="40€")
    product3 = Product(code="3", descripcion="Destronillador", precio="20€")
    
    # Agregar los productos al catálogo
    catalogue.add_product(product1)
    catalogue.add_product(product2)
    catalogue.add_product(product3)
    # Mostrar el contenido del catálogo de productos
    catalogue.mostrar_todos()

    # Intento insertar un producto que ya existe en el catalogo. EL producto no se agrega al catálogo e imprime un mensaje informativo.
    catalogue.add_product(product1)
```

Comment: He actualizado el código inicial añadiendo el código que me ha guiado el profesor... Pero la verdad que no lo entiendo. ¿Alguien lo puede explicar?

Answer (score 0):

No me acuerdo bien de la sintaxis de python pero seria algo asi:

1º Crea un producto

----> `nuevoProducto = new Product("miCodigoProduct", "La descripcion", "50€")`

2º Crea un catalogo

---->`NuevoCatalogo = new Catalogue ()`

3º Pasar Producto como parametro a Catalogo

---->`NuevoCatalogo.add_product(nuevoProducto)`

4º Cambia la funcion add_product

---->En vez de:

```
  def add_product(self,code,descripcion,precio):
        self.code= code.product
        self.decripcion = descripcion.product
        self.precio = precio.product
```

Pon algo como :

```
def add_product(self, product):
      self.code = product.code
      self.description = product.description
      self.precio = product.precio
```

Answer (score 0):

tu código es correcto, y por lo que veo, creaste un diccionario para almacenar los productos, donde la llave para obtener el objeto esta asociado a su código de producto.

te sugiero que para mantener lo que ya desarrollaste, crees un método remove_product dentro de la clase Catalogo que reciba como parámetro el código y elimines del diccionario el producto de la siguiente manera:

```
def remove_product( self, product_code ):
    del self.catalogo[product_code]
```

Por otra parte, para iterar el diccionario se requiere hacer lo siguiente:

```
for product_code, product in catalogo.items():
    print(product_code, "::", product )
```

Suerte

PD: Te sugiero que mantengas los nombres de clases y sus miembros en ingles o en español. Si tu propósito es iterar frecuentemente los diccionarios, es mejor que optes por una lista.

Comment: Perdona por mi poco conocimiento, intento aprender... Pero no entiendo como implementar el código. Entiendo que para borrar un producto sería ==> def remove_product(self,product.code)- más que nada en todo mi código no lo he puesto con guión bajo). Luego pasaría como objeto, por ejemplo(==> t.remove_product ). Espero que me disculpes por mi falta de conocimiento.

Comment: debes agregar el metodo remove_product en tu clase catalogue